# Is $z$ a point on the line $[x,y]=\{tx+(1-t)y: t\in[0,1]\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

In a normed space $M$ with $x,y,z\in M$, i  need show if this statement is true or false.

$\|x-y \|= \|x-z \| + \|z-y \|$ if and only if $z$ is a point on the line $[x,y]=\{tx+(1-t)y: t\in[0,1]\}$

I showed the direction $(\Leftarrow)$ and think that in general the other direction $(\Rightarrow)$ is not true but can't find an example for this.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the $L^1$ norm to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\Bbb R^2$, consider the norm $\|(a,b)\|_\infty=\max\{|a|,|b|\}$. Then, if $x=(-1,0)$, $y=(1,0)$, and $z=(0,1)$, you have$$\|x-y\|_\infty=2=\overbrace{\|x-z\|_\infty}^{\phantom1=1}+\overbrace{\|z-y\|_\infty}^{\phantom1=1}.$$However,$$z\notin\{tx+(1-t)y\mid t\in[0,1]\}.$$